# No such file found in jenkis pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Here is my groovy file
timestamps{
  node('cf_slave'){
    checkout scm

```
stage('Read the file') {
    def PWD = pwd()
    withEnv(["prj_option=${params.project}"]) {
        def response =sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'sh \'jenkins/security/get_values.sh\'')
        }
    }
```

This is my get_values.sh file

```
echo "The project option is:" $prj_option

prj_name=$(echo "$prj_option" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
file_name="va_input_file_$prj_name.txt"

echo "The project option is:" $file_name
ls -la
chmod 775 jenkins/security/$file_name
ls -la

get_input_values() {
  file=$1
  IFS=''
  while read line
    do
    if [ `echo ${line} | grep -E -c -w "NAME_SPACE" ` -gt 0 ]; then
      NAME_SPACE=$(echo " ${line}" | cut -d'=' -f2)
      echo "The name space value is $NAME_SPACE"
    elif [ `echo ${line} | grep -E -c -w "IMAGE_NAMES" ` -gt 0 ]; then
      values=$(echo " ${line}" | cut -d'=' -f2)
      echo "THE DOCKERIMAGES are $DOCKER_IMAGES_NAMES"
    else
      echo "Please provide input for namespace and docker images to be scanned by VA_TOOl"
    fi
  done < ${file}
}


images=$(get_input_values ${file_name})
```

so here my text file is under jenkins/security folder of gitrepo but unfortunately I am getting this error:

````
16:05:28 + sh jenkins/security/get_values.sh
16:05:28 jenkins/security/get_values.sh: 16: jenkins/security/get_values.sh: cannot open va_input_file_icp.txt: No such file```
````

Comment: Provide more details, such as errors and code.

Comment: here is the code which I am getting when trying to read the contents of the file in my jenkins job: ```ash jenkins/security/va_pull_docker_images.sh
14:42:06 jenkins/security/va_pull_docker_images.sh: line 27: file.txt: No such file or directory```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is a ticket for this in Jenkins (https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-51245) which was closed as a duplicate of this ticket: (https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27413)

JENKINS-27413 was raised in 2015, and is still open. The File Parameter appears not to work in Jenkins Pipeline. It does however work when used in a Freestyle project. While not ideal, I would recommend changing your job to be a Freestyle project if that's feasible.

Comment: ok.. Is there any way how I can send inputs from file in jenkins pipeline as I don't want to change my job from pipeline to freestyle

Comment: Sorry @Madhuri but that is a VERY broad question ... there are lots of different ways to do things in Jenkins Pipelines. Can you give a clearer example of what the file you're passing might be? Could it be in a Git Repo and fetched as part of the job?

Comment: yup I am going through with this option, which is working in a way. But here again I am facing some issue. Here is my scenario which I am trying in pipeline: In my pipeline checking out my git repo using scm and then, as part of my pipeline stage I am calling one of the shell script. In that shell script it is trying to read one of the text file which is part of git repo. But I am getting no such file found error. Could you help me if I am doing anything error

Comment: When you write that you "read one of the text files",how are you doing that? If you are using the `out_string = readFile( existing_file_in_repo.txt )` pipeline command, that works well for me.